# SELECT request for uniqueness validation has no WHERE conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I'm searching 4 days about this problem, I get some troubles with ActiveRecord and validation using uniqueness.
I cannot create a Model containing at least one uniqueness validation in console or test. But, I can create objects using the rails server (API).

This is making me crazy ! It's started when I updated a Rails3 project to Rails4.

### Actually, I use the following gems :

- Rails 4.0.15
- Ruby 2.2.0
- FactoryGirl Rails 4.6.0
- Rspec 3.4.1
- PG 0.18.4

### The related model :

```
class ContainerType < BaseModel

  has_many :containers, :inverse_of => :container_type, :dependent => :restrict_with_exception

  validates :name, :length => { :minimum => 1, :maximum => 25 },
                   :presence => true,
                   :uniqueness => true
end
```

`BaseModel` is an abstract containing some `include` common to all models.

```
class BaseModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  include [...]
end
```

### Testing in console :

`test = ContainerType.last.dup`

> ContainerType Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "container_types".* FROM "container_types"   ORDER BY "container_types"."id" DESC LIMIT 1

`<ContainerType id: nil, name: "Type #1-6f896a99-fb63-4b3", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

`test.save!`

> (0.3ms)  BEGIN
>        ContainerType Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "container_types" LIMIT 1
>      (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
>      ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name has already been taken
>   from /home/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.15/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'

For a Valid ContainerType :

```
ContainerType.delete_all
ContainerType.create!(name: 'my container type 1 !')
```

> (0.3ms)  BEGIN
>        ContainerType Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "container_types" LIMIT 1
>      (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
>      ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name has already been taken
>   from /home/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.15/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'

You may noticed the SELECT request for validation has no conditions. 
I'm sure it's related to ActiveRecord or an incompatible gem, but I cannot find why....

Othe tests :

```
container_type = ContainerType.where(name: 'my container type 1 !').first_or_create
```

> ContainerType Load (0.6ms) SELECT "container_types".* FROM "container_types" WHERE "container_types"."name" = 'my container type 1 !' ORDER BY "container_types"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
>   (0.1ms) BEGIN
>   ContainerType Exists (0.3ms) SELECT 1 AS one FROM "container_types" LIMIT 1
>   (0.2ms) ROLLBACK

```
p container_type.inspect
```

> `"#<ContainerType id: nil, name: \"my container type 1 !\", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>"`

test

### So the questions are :

- What could make the uniqueness validations create SQL request with no conditions ?
- Have you already see this ?

### EDIT :

After some investigation, I tried : 
- add `return true` on all before_* callbacks
- create a custom validator for uniqueness validation
- I generate a scaffold model to check if it's related to my generic includes.

### I think :

It's seems to be related to the models attribute, with the rails update I added the StrongParameter to my controllers. But models might be still using a kind of protected_attribute relic.

Comment: You could try setting the case sensitive property to false on the uniqueness validator, like so: `validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }`

Comment: @D.Visser : I tried and there is no changes...

Comment: It seems to me that it's working exactly as it should. When you run `ContainerType.last.dup` you are duplicating the attributes from the the last created ContainerType. You have a uniqueness validation on `name`...when you call `save` that object isn't able to save because it has the same name as another object.

Comment: @toddmetheny Oops, I forgot the valid case.... I update the question.

Comment: after `delete_all` can you ensure that the objects have been destroyed? could you post the relevant stack trace you get from running `delete_all`? Do you get the same thing when using `destroy` instead? Perhaps there are related callbacks that should run but aren't? what if you `reload!` the console after running `delete_all` but before calling `create!`?

Comment: @toddmetheny : The `reload!` after a `delete_all` work ! I can create my object. But the next creations fail...

Comment: After the `delete_all` I can directly create a new record. The `reload!` doesn't seems to be related. When I `destroy_all` I get the following message : `ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError: Cannot delete record because of dependent containers` which is normal as I have a dependent destroy.

Comment: don't you want to destroy in order to avoid orphaning those other records? I would make sure that the record doesn't still exist before trying to create. Try calling `container_type = ContainerType.where(name: 'my container type 1 !').first_or_create` (will return it if it exists and otherwise create it) and then `p container_type.inspect`

Comment: I added the `first_or_create` test in the question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my intern found why it wasn't working, it's coming from a monkey_patch in the project. A lib loaded from the initializers, was overriding the ActiveRecord::Relation class...